# Bitmap does not save to gallery on some android devices

Tags: java, android, android-gallery, mediastore

On some devices following code does not save the bitmap to the gallery. I was told this is a Samsung device.
Is there any improvements I can make to resolve this issue.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... data) {
        try {
            if (data.length > 0 && data[0] == null) return null;
            ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
            String fileName = "XF_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()) + ".jpg";
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + mContext.getString(R.string.app_name));
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1);
            } else {
                File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                if(!directory.exists()){
                    directory.mkdirs();
                }
                File file = new File(directory, fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            OutputStream output = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);
            data[0].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            Log.d("myApp", "Image saved!");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("myApp", "Image saved!" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("myApp", "Image saved!" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your code distinghuishes between version Q.